# In Android, Can One Intercept Key Events Globally Before They Reach the Child View That Has Focus?

Tags: android, events, event-handling, keyboard, key

In most circumstances, I want key events to be processed by the (child) view that presently has focus, which is the default behavior, and also is what I presently have implemented.

However, under certain very specific circumstances, I would like to temporarily intercept and handle all key events (including specifically those normally handled by the child views) either in my current activity or, failing that, in my root view (it doesn't matter, so long as they are processed globally - I don't care about hardware buttons like volume +/-, as these are not handled in any of my child views anyway).

For *touch* events, we have onInterceptTouchEvent(), which allows a ViewGroup to watch touch events as they are dispatched to child views, and to block receipt of those events (when desired) by the child views for which they are intended.

Unfortunately, I can't find anything analogous to onInterceptTouchEvent() for key events.  Am I missing something obvious, or is this an actual asymmetry in the OS?

Of course, I could just wire the current key event handler code of every child view to directly call a method on the main activity to handle the event if it wants to, and to have that activity-level method return a boolean that indicates whether it handled the event.  Then, the child view could handle the event if and only if the activity method it invoked had *not* handled it.

But I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to simply intercept the traffic on its way "down" the hierarchy to the child view, just as onInterceptTouchEvent() does for touch events.

Comment: Note that I'm also interested in answers that state that this *cannot* be done.  If verified, such an answer could be accepted, as well.

Comment: I am also curious to learn about why this capability would exist for touch events, but not for key events, if that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `OnGlobalFocusChangeListener` to your root view. Let's do that per activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(android.R.id.content).getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalFocusChanged(View oldFocus, View newFocus) {
            if (newFocus instanceof EditText) {
                ((EditText) newFocus).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        //process whatever you want
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Of course if you are interested in views other than `EditText` you have to figure out how to observe their changes.

As well if you want to add it globally to all of your activities use `Application#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` to use that code in all of your activities.

Answer (score 0):

All widgets/Views seem to implement [`KeyEvent.Callback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html) , which has methods to be called for key down, long press, multiple and key up. All of these methods return boolean values explained as:

> If you handled the event, return true. If you want to allow the event
>   to be handled by the next receiver, return false.

I think you can try overriding these methods in parent components.

The other one is [`dispatchKeyEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) of `View` it handles dispatching events down the focus path. Overriding this can be tried also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

1) Unless I'm mistaken, the methods declared by the KeyEvent.Callback interface, such as onKeyDown(), are invoked first for the view that presently has focus.  It is only if that view returns false from one of these methods that other, ancestor, views get a shot at it.

I'm interested in having the root view (or the activity) gain access to events *before* the view having focus.

2) I believe that dispatchKeyEvent() *generates* a key event programmatically.  What I'm trying to do is *intercept* an event generated as a result of the *user* having tapped a keyboard key.

Comment: I see. How about grabbing and holding the focus ?

Comment: Hmm, yes, I can see how some people facing a similar problem might take the approach of, say, calling setFocusable(false) for the child views in question, if that is what you have in mind.  The problem with that for me is that I want the user to be able to continue to use touch in those views to select and to navigate.  I just want to disable keyboard input processing by those child views, and replace it with global processing of the same keystrokes, when certain conditions are detected (at the global level).

Comment: As mentioned in the original question, I do have other ways to accomplish my goals, but none as elegant as being able to intercept events at the root view (or activity) level would be.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `dispatchKeyEvent` in a `ViewGroup` which is ancestral to the `View`s to be disabled works.

I am using the following~.

```
public static class TvPrefsContainer extends FrameLayout {
    private boolean isActive; // i.e. will dispatch keyboard events to focused children
    // snip

    @Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        return isActive && super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}

public static class TvPrefs extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.tv_prefs);
    }
}

private void togglePrefsVis() {
    tvPrefsContainer.animate()
            .alpha(isPrefsVisible ? 0 : 1)
            .translationX(isPrefsVisible ? tvPrefsContainer.getMeasuredWidth() : 0)
            .start();
    tvPrefsContainer.isActive = isPrefsVisible;
    isPrefsVisible = !isPrefsVisible;
}
```

Comment: I am wrong about `isActivated`. At the very least it contributes to the states used for StateListDrawables

Comment: I think dispatchKeyEventPreIme (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchKeyEventPreIme(android.view.KeyEvent) ) will be more helpfull